# R find min x by 2 groups

Tags: r, loops, data.table

What is the minimum `DSSite_Dis` for each `SiteID` within each `year`?

I have tried:

```
ds_DT <- ds_fish[ , .SD[which.min(DSSite_Dis)], by = c("SiteID", "year")]
```

however `SiteID` and `year` are different lengths.

I can't get my head around looping this by iterating through `year` within `SiteID`.`which.min` is a `data.table` function but happy to use something else.

Comment: You should provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and the desired output for that input so that possible solutions can be tested and verified.

Answer (score 3):

`SiteID` and `year` *aren't* different lengths. It may well be the case that `ds_fish[ , uniqueN(SiteID)]` is different from `ds_fish[ , uniqueN(year)]`, but by the nature of `ds_fish` being a `data.table`, it *must* be the case that `length(ds_fish$SiteID) == length(ds_fish$year)` (in turn both are equal to `nrow(ds_fish)`).

The code you provided is close to what you want. Here's what you want:

```
ds_fish[ , .(min_site_dis = min(DSSite_Dis)), by = .(SiteID, year)]
```

What you've done is return *the full observation* for each minimal `DSSite_Dis` -- this will return not only the minimal `DSSite_Dis`, but also the values of the remaining columns of `ds_fish` in the rows corresponding to these minima.

A conceptual note for you to chew on -- you phrased what you're after as "the minimum `DSSite_Dis` for each `SiteID` within each `year`"; you should convince yourself that this is the same as the minimum `DISSite_Dis` for each *`year`* within each *`SiteID`*.

Answer (score 0):

Original code works now.

Here it is in full

```
library(foreign)
library(data.table)

file <- 'DownstreamSites.dbf' # ds_fish dbf
ds_fish <- read.dbf(file, as.is = FALSE)
file <- 'UpstreamSites.dbf' # nearest_us_fish dbf
us_fish <- read.dbf(file, as.is = FALSE)
file <- 'barriers.dbf' # barriers dbf
barriers <- read.dbf(file, as.is = FALSE)
file <- 'metrics.dbf' # barriers dbf
metrics <- read.dbf(file, as.is = FALSE)
metrics <- metrics[c(-1:-3,-8:-34,-41,-42,-45:-47,-49:-52)]

colnames(metrics)[13] <- "DSSite_ID"
ds_fish1 <- merge(metrics, ds_fish, by = 'DSSite_ID')
colnames(metrics)[13] <- "USSite_ID"
us_fish1 <- merge(metrics, us_fish, by = 'USSite_ID')

year <- format(as.Date(us_fish1$event_date, format="%d/%m/%Y"),"%Y")
us_fish1$year <- year
year <- format(as.Date(ds_fish1$event_date, format="%d/%m/%Y"),"%Y")
ds_fish1$year <- year

ds_fish2 <- data.table(ds_fish1)
us_fish2 <- data.table(us_fish1)

ds_DT <- ds_fish2[ , .SD[which.min(DSSite_Dis)], by = c("SiteID", "year")]
us_DT <- us_fish2[ , .SD[which.min(USSite_Dis)], by = c("SiteID", "year")]
```